# Ordinary Differential Equation - Why is this working?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I stumbled over this ordinary differential equation recently:

() = ‘‘‘‘()

I am really at the very very beginning of differential equations, but can somebody explain why this works:

So as a possible solution, you assume the function is exp(λx) with some λ ∈ ℂ.

Taking the fourth derivative yields
d/dx(exp(λx))= λ⁴ exp(λx). We can cancel out exp(λx) as it is not equal to zero ∀  ∈ ℂ.

So we have λ⁴ = 1.
Complex roots of unity yield
λ = 1, λ = -1, λ = i, λ = -i.

I completely got that part, it is very elegant, but now comes the point where I got lost.

The author concludes that every solution of this ODE has to be a sum of the exp(λx) terms with different choices out of those four lambdas with respective coefficients a,b,c,d ∈ ℂ.

Why is this true? Is there a theorem about that?

I suppose it is from linear algebra as this looks like a linear combination.

Comment: The steps to prove are: (1) Each of these exponentials is a solution - Done, by construction. (2) The equation is linear, thus linear combinations are solutions - Should be in your background. (3) There are no other solutions - Any initial condition can be realized with these linear combinations, then apply the uniqueness theorem.

Comment: Thank you - I got it!